# python string formating problem with including "{ }" part of the string

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting

i try to format the string to be:

```
${name123}
```

without string quotes between curly brackets.
what i try to do :

```
dbname ="name123"
 db_name = f'\${ {dbname} }'
 print(db_name)
```

but the result is :

```
\${'name123'}
```

also i try with format :

```
dbname ="name123"
 db_name = f'\${ {0} }'.format(dbname)
 print(db_name)
```

but the result is :

```
\$name123
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
dbname = "name123"
db_name = "${{{}}}".format(dbname)
print(db_name)
```

Prints:

```
${name123}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a = 'name123'
b = ('${' + a + '}')
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
${name123}
```